# How to execute this block of code on every controller methods' call?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API (.NET 4) project and I'd want to execute this block of code every time a controller method gets called:

```
        try
        {
            //ctx is an Entity Framework context object and 'this' is ApiController
            if (!Common.PortalSecurity.IsAccessGranted(userName, ctx, this))
            {
                return Common.Communication.Http.ReturnErrorMessage(new Exception(
                    string.Format(PortalResources.ErrorAccessDenied, Common.PortalSecurity.GetUriSegments(this.Request))), this);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return Common.Communication.Http.ReturnErrorMessage(new Exception(PortalResources.ErrorSecurity), this);
        }
```

`Common.Communication.Http.ReturnErrorMessage` returns an HttpResponseMessage.

I thought of the controller constructor, but at this point, `ApiController.Request` is still null.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Custom Attributes/Action filters

Comment: http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-webapi/

Comment: @Justin. Very useful Justin. I had looked into basic auth, but somehow the filter part escaped me.